# SQL: Engineering new features using UPDATE SET

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, feature-engineering

I'm trying to create a new feature, user_count, which displays the number of times a particular user appears in a dataset. Here is a snapshot of the original dataset:

[image: dataset]

Here is the SQL code that I have written to try to achieve this (used in GoogleCloud's BigQuery):

```
UPDATE `project-feat-eng.ednetv1.smalltrain` AS t
SET t.user_count = target.total_questions_answered
FROM (
SELECT user_id, count(user_id) AS total_questions_answered
FROM `project-feat-eng.ednetv1.smalltrain` 
GROUP BY user_id) AS target
WHERE target.user_id = t.user_id
```

The problem is that user_count is not a feature in the original table, so cannot be updated. Can the above code be adapted to create the user_count feature successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot introduce new column using `UPDATE` syntax. Rather you should use `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` syntax (with below query) to create new table or replace existing

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS user_count
FROM `project-feat-eng.ednetv1.smalltrain`
```

Or, as an option, you can use `ALTER TABLE` to add new column first and then use your `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Thanks very much - this works exactly as intended, but does not permanently change the table. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what you mean by `does not permanently change the table.`? it actually does! obviously select statement by itself does not, but if you use it as a part of create or replace statement - it does! just try

Comment: you should do `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE \`project-feat-eng.ednetv1.smalltrain\` AS SELECT ... `